# .NET date, Moment.js, UTC and Timezone shifting

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I've got a **UTC** date through an Ajax call, e.g. `"/Date(1517216466000+0100)/"`, 
which is when printing to the console: `Mon Jan 29 2018 10:01:06 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)`. 
What I need to do, is to let the user change the timezones: I can easily do it with e.g. `moment(myDate).tz("Japan")`. 
 
Then I need to save the date in it's UTC format, which I am not able to do.
I've been experimenting with `moment.utc()`, but for the input above, it returns **1 hour less**. 
How to deal with this situation? In summary:
 1. Get a UTC time from a webservice 
 2. Let the user change the timezones 
3. Save the modified date in UTC (without the timezone)

Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kqrct7?file=app%2Fapp.component.html 


EDIT for clarification: 
Let's just have a look at the hours. What I get the date from the WCF, is 10 o'clock. The browser interprets it as 10 o'clock BUT in GMT+1 so when I convert it to UTC, it becomes 9 o'clock. 
I want it to be 10 o'clock **as UTC**. Then, if I modify the timezone and e.g. the minutes of this date, I want to be able to get the UTC value of this date.

EDIT2: Made my question simplier for clarification

1. I've got a UTC date, which I get from a webservice like: "/Date(1517216466000+0100)/" which is: Mon Jan 29 2018 10:01:06 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time) when printed to console.
2. I add a timezone to it with moment(this.inputDate).tz("Europe/Berlin").format(), but it stays 10:01:06, I guess because of my browsers GMT+1.
3. I want the ORIGINAL string to be used as a UTC date AND it should remain 10:01:06, not 09:01:06 as you can see above (2nd moment example), so with the timezone "Europe/Berlin" would be 11:01:6

Comment: Can you explain your problem using actual example values and show where it's going wrong.

Comment: `Save the modified date in UTC (without the timezone)`  UTC has no timezone, that's the whole point. :)

Comment: @Keith description updated

Comment: @phuzi more details added

Comment: Could you explain in simple terms what it is your trying to do..?  Date/Time in Javascript can be a little bit confusing and you can end up over complicating things when not required.  Basically all date-time's in Javascript visually work in locale time, but internally work in UTC, think of things this way might help.

Comment: @Keith: question updated

Comment: Still not really sure what your after,..  But maybe this might help `moment(moment("/Date(1517216466000+0100)/").tz("Europe/Berlin").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"))`, what this will do is format a UTC time into Berlin time, and then format this to UTC, from this UTC you could then ask for in Japan by just adding `.tz("Japan").format()`, that btw, equals => `2018-01-29T19:01:06`

Comment: `I add a timezone to it with`, well no you don't, remember what I said, internally all date times are UTC, this is just telling moment how to treat locale time for display purposes, but internally it's still the same time you started with in UTC. :)

Comment: `moment(moment("/Date(1517216466000+0100)/").tz("Europe/Berlin").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")).tz("Europe/Berlin").format()`  And here it is shown in `Europe/Berlin`, and it gives you the 11'oclock.  In a nutshell what you are wanting to do is convert the datetime into berlin locale time, to UTC, but the source is expressed as UTC, when in fact it's a locale time.

Comment: @Keith Yes, you are right. The date is stored as a UTC, but interpreted as a local time, "thanks" to the browser. That's what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your detailed answers, they helped me a lot in understanding my problem! However, the right solution was the following: 
 
10 o'clock was a UTC time in the database and it got interpreted as 9 o'clock UTC in Moment.js because C# handled it as a **local** time. So, before sending the date to the client, I had to indicate that its a UTC:

```
var utcToClient = DateTime.SpecifyKind(downtime.DownTimeStartUTC, DateTimeKind.Utc)
```

Then, in Moment I could create a UTC with:

```
var jsUtc = moment.utc(downtime.DownTimeStartUTC)
```

Changing the timezones was a breeze with:

```
jsUtc.tz(userSelectedTimezone)
```

And saving the date in the database, I used this in C#:

```
var utcFromClient = Record.DownTimeStartUTC.ToUniversalTime()
```

Answer (score 4):

In the [.NET JSON formatted date](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjmitC7__3YAhUHTLwKHXaECzwQFghBMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hanselman.com%2Fblog%2FOnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx&usg=AOvVaw10Y731AC-PCHX8kuTFyGS_) "/Date(1517216466000+0100)/" the timezone offset can be ignored. It represents "2018-01-29T09:01:06.000Z", where the source system was at a timezone offset of +0100. So if you don't care about the source timezone, just ignore it.

It is also an identical moment in time to Mon Jan 29 2018 10:01:06 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time), just with a different offset.

UTC is not a format, it's a time standard. If you want to use ISO 8601 format:

1. Extract the first numeric value
2. Convert to Number
3. Pass to the Date constructor
4. Call the *toISOString* method on the resulting Date

```js
var s = '/Date(-1517216466000+0100)/';
console.log(new Date(+s.replace(/^[^\d-]+(-?\d+).*$/,'$1')).toISOString());
```

You can also parse and format it using moment.js, which according to [the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/) can handle the .NET JSON format without needing to specify the format. So you can either do that or extract the time value and parse it with the "x" format token:

```js
var s = '/Date(1517216466000+0100)/';

// Let moment.js guess the format
console.log(moment(s).utc());

// Extract time value and supply format
console.log(moment(s.replace(/^[^\d-]+(-?\d+).*$/,'$1'), 'x').utc());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It seems to me that Moment supports this format: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/

Comment: The offset is included in the serialized value because the .NET `DateTime.Kind` was `Unspecified`, serialized as if it were `Local`. Alternatively, if you set its kind to `Utc`, it will be serialized as `'/Date(-1517216466000)/'` which indicates it was a UTC value in .Net.

Answer (score 1):

`"/Date(1517216466000+0100)/"` is a non-standard way to serialise a date/time. Take a look at [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which defines several standard ways to represent dates and times.

That being said let's take a look at what this gets evaluated as...

```
moment("/Date(1517216466000+0100)/").toDate()
```

gives `Mon Jan 29 2018 09:01:06 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)` for me (in the UK)

taking just the timestamp value `1517216466000`

```
new Date(1517216466000)
```

also gives `Mon Jan 29 2018 09:01:06 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)`

this means that the `+0100` is being ignored.

You're not actually modifying the time so why would you expect it to save back as anything other than `Mon Jan 29 2018 09:01:06`

**UPDATE**

But the "original" string represents `Mon Jan 29 2018 09:01:06 UTC` the `+0100` is ignored and it's just coincidence that your offset to UTC is also `+0100`. An off.

Offset and timezone are 2 different things. A timezone encompasses offset to UTC as well as when/if daylight savings comes in to force. Just because it says +0100 doesn't necessarily mean (W. Europe Standard Time) as it could just as easily be (West Africa Time) which is also UTC+0100 but doesn't observe daylight savings at all.

The time you have `"/Date(1517216466000+0100)/"` doesn't convey enough information to say which timezone it is and JS/moment just uses the timestamp `1517216466000` and as such uses UTC. When you `console.log()` this the browser writes it to screen as local time `Mon Jan 29 2018 10:01:06 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)` but this is only a representation of the underlying datetime.

By telling moment to use a specific time zone, it's only changing how the date/time gets displayed and doesn't actually change the time it represents.

If you use a date picker to change the date/time then you'll have to serialise the value to send to the backend in an appropriate way that the .Net app you cannot change will understand and conveys what you intend.

***Example***

1. Get date from server as `var serverTime = "/Date(1517216466000+0100)/"`
2. convert this to a JS Date using moment `var time = new moment(serverTime)`
3. Let user specify TimeZone i.e. Japan Standard Time (UTC+9) `time = time.tz("Japan")`
4. `time` still represents `Mon Jan 29 2018 09:01:06 UTC` but when displayed on screen with `time.format()` gives `"2018-01-29T18:01:06+09:00"`

You stated "I want it to be 10 o'clock as UTC". Unfortunately the value you've is **NOT** 10 O'clock UTC and will never be 10 O'clock UTC because it isn't. **It is 9 O'clock UTC**

You could parse the value you get from the server yourself but the time from the server **IS** 9am UTC. If you change it to 10 am UTC then you would see that as `Mon Jan 29 2018 11:01:06 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)` - 11 O'clock local time.

Comment: I do modify the time, using Material Datepicker and a dropdown for the timezone conversion, I just left it out of my example to make it simplier.

Comment: Secondly, unfortunately I cannot change the string timeformat, because it's part of an old .NET app.

Comment: @flow3r "part of an old .NET app." thought so. If the value being saved back is incorrect then it might have been a good idea to include the code/example of what you are doing so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but I think, we might talk about something different. There's an Oracle date in the database, which is said to be UTC. That's 10 o'clock, in the database, but when I try to parse it on the client side, it becomes 10 o'clock local time. This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: If it's 10 O'clock UTC in the database then it sounds like there's a problem with the .Net app in the way it's handling `DateTime`s. Can you confirm that the date is actually stored as UTC in the database? As it looks like it's treating it as local time

Comment: .NET reads it from the database as a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of `Unspecified`. I learned the hard way I had to correct the `Kind` to `Utc` when pulling it from the database. If you don't, the value is serialized as if it were `Local` to the machine serializing it. Microsoft never did get time zones right.